# Upgrading a Windows Phone 7.5 Application with Isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, marketplace

I have an application on Marketplace, the application uses Isolated storage.

I have an update to the app which fixes a few bugs and also adds the facility to connect and sync with my website (which is a cloud based version of the same app).

My question is; what is the risk of the isostore getting wiped or corrupted during the upgrade? Is the protocol to warn users or do we assume that they regularly back up their phones and consider this a non issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that isolated storage remains intact (after all, this is why there are dedicated APIs for upgrading database schema in-place) - it's only if an application is uninstalled, does it's isolated storage get wiped as well.

Answer (score 2):

As Rowland said, The `Isolated storage` wipes off only if the application is uninstalled. If you have changed the way data is written or read from storage in update, make sure the update does not break anything.

[Isolated Storage Best Practices for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769544%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. My concern was regarding the risk of for example changing the columns within a table object but it seems that the (code first style or similar) data pattern is robust.